# php, laravel) Displaying random images using the same URL

Tags: php, html, laravel, image-processing

I want to create a site that provides images outside.

But, I want to show a random image even if the image uses the same url.

For example, if I use http://www.example.com/test.jpg">, I want to show test1.jpg or test2.jpg on my server at random (or on other conditions).

Is this possible? I know that browser users pre-store the cache in a temporary folder and recycle it.
But Is there any way?

Alternatively, is it possible to have the various images randomly displayed by typing http://www.example.com/test?

Thanks your advice in advance.

Comment: `<img src='myscript.php'>` would be one way, then the script can pick a random image each time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In **routes\web.php** just make a Get route like this:

```
   Route::get('test.jpg',function(){
  $images=['test1.jpg','test2.jpg','test3.jpg'];
  $randimage=shuffle($images);
 return '<image src="images/'.$images[0].'">';
});
```

the [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function change the ordering of items so that in every request you'll see a new image in that route
 
(it's just an example,better to use a controller and code in there bro) 
hope be helpfull

Comment: I don't think a URL named `test.jpg` should respond with *HTML*.

Comment: @deceze if you know it's Laravel route and every character are possible my friend, I tested that code in localhost not just post it as an answer unconsciously...